# Modifying antd Select component

Tags: reactjs, select, antd

Went through inspect trying to find a class responsible for changing the color of the option once mouse is on it, so would appreciate if anyone know who is responsible for such behavior.Thank you

I am using https://ant.design/components/select/

[image]

Comment: How is it related to Java?  Possibly this tag should be removed.

Comment: Use devtools and override the classname